# No route To Host error when requesting localhost but curl request is successfull

Tags: java, linux, rest, httpclient, resttemplate

I am trying to make a POST request from one service to another service from my Java code. Both of the services are always running on the same server
I am using restTemplate for this. Request URL :

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-protobuf");
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "text/plain");
    org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<byte[]> request = new org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<>(definitions.toByteArray(), headers);
    String url =  "http://localhost:8888/product-details/api/1.0/external_launches";
    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, Void.class);
```

When I ran this code on one of my linux servers, this is the error I got :

```
2022-05-06 08:42:32,979 [209: Normal Priority Request Pool-62] ERROR test_appliance - I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8888/product-details/api/1.0/external_launches": No route to host (Host unreachable); nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable):org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8888/product-details/api/1.0/external_launches": No route to host (Host unreachable); nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8888/product-details/api/1.0/external_launches": No route to host (Host unreachable); nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:675) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:622) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:540) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]
```

But when I ssh into the linux box and make a curl request like this

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8888/product-details/api/1.0/external_launches
```

It works fine

The main problem I have is that this kind of behaviour is only reproducible in 1 of my linux machines. I have 3 other linux machines on which the Java code works perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there a drawback to using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Is your /etc/hosts file corrupted?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz i tried using 127.0.0.1 as well. Same result

Comment: Can you use `localhost2` and paste error messages for the other three servers ?

Comment: @Philippe the error is "Connection Timed out"

Comment: @UjjwalMaheshwari have you resolved this issue? I am facing similar issue now